# Elasticsearch - Can't search using suggestion field ("is not a completion suggest field")

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

In elastic search I'm storing records in the `trends` namespace and `trend` topic. These are simple objects with only a `name` (string) and `id`.

I want to search by name via autocomplete, and for that I'm trying to use the indexed search.

Here's my code to add the index to the name column. Here I'm using a `name_suggest` column into which I insert the *same data* as the `name` column, and is used in the query as well.

```
  def self.index_column_mappings
    elasticsearch.index({
      index: "trends",
      type: "trend",
      body: {
        mappings: {
          trend: {
            properties: {
              name: {
                type: "string"
              },
              name_suggest: {
                type: "completion"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })
  end
```

To start out with I `DELETE *`. Then I add this column mapping and add some records. Next I run this to search:

```
  def suggest(term)
    @client.search({
      index: "trends",
      type: "trend",
      body: {
        suggest: {
          name_suggest: {
            prefix: term,
            completion: {
              field: "name_suggest"
            }
          }
        }
      }  
    })
  end
```

and I get the following error:

> Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Field [name_suggest] is not a completion suggest field"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"trends","node":"YVcINtPlSU2u8R2lT9VxPQ","reason":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Field [name_suggest] is not a completion suggest field"}}],"caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Field [name_suggest] is not a completion suggest field"}},"status":400}
>   from /home/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-5.0.3/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:201:in `__raise_transport_error'

It seems the important part is this: **Field [name_suggest] is not a completion suggest field**. I don't understand how I'm failing to set the field up.

btw i'm using Elastic search 5.x

---

In response to comments here is the result for `GET /trends/_mapping`:

```
{
   "trends": {
      "mappings": {
         "trend": {
            "properties": {
               "id": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "mappings": {
                  "properties": {
                     "trend": {
                        "properties": {
                           "properties": {
                              "properties": {
                                 "name": {
                                    "properties": {
                                       "type": {
                                          "type": "text",
                                          "fields": {
                                             "keyword": {
                                                "type": "keyword",
                                                "ignore_above": 256
                                             }
                                          }
                                       }
                                    }
                                 },
                                 "name_suggest": {
                                    "properties": {
                                       "type": {
                                          "type": "text",
                                          "fields": {
                                             "keyword": {
                                                "type": "keyword",
                                                "ignore_above": 256
                                             }
                                          }
                                       }
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               },
               "name": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                     "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                     }
                  }
               },
               "name_suggest": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                     "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post mappin you have right now ?

Comment: N you are not, its code which puts mapping. Open in browser SERVER:9200/trends/_mapping?pretty

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat see update

Comment: do you see that mapping is wrong? As i said in my answer delete INDEX, then make sure index is created, then start indexing your data

Comment: I am not sure how ruby works maybe its async so you could sent two requests at the same time.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're asking me to do. I already am running `DELETE /*`  which should destroy the mapping I think. Then I create it using the ruby command I show.

Comment: I am not asking you anything i am just trying to help you. MApping you have posted is wrong "name_suggest": { "type": "text",

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat I know, i appreciate you. The thing is I am saying `name_suggest: {type: "completion"}` when i create the mapping, so I don't know why it's being incorrect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135338/discussion-between-volodymyr-bilyachat-and-maxple).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final answer.
You are using wrong method to index data. Look for [example here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/blob/master/elasticsearch-api/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/indices/create.rb)

```
 def self.index_column_mappings
     client.indices.create({
      index: "trends",
      body: {
        mappings: {
          trend: {
            properties: {
                name:  { type: 'string' },
                name_suggest:  { type: 'completion' }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })
  end
```

Comment: Like I said I am deleting all data before testing.